# How can I fill an array with a callback func result in javascript?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Let's say I have something like this:

```
window.dayNames = function () {
 let names = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    names.push(moment().day(i).format('dddd'));
 }
 return names;
}
```

Is there a cleaner shorthand to have it with js? 
e.g. I was looking at lodash lib _.fill

I was wondering if exists Something like:

```
 _.fill(0,7, (i) => {return moment().day(i).format('dddd');});
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
Array.from({length:7}, (_, i) => moment().day(i).format('dddd'))
```

> `Array.from()` has an optional parameter `mapFn`, which allows you to
>   execute a map function on each element of the array

Answer (score 3):

You can use lodash's [`_.times()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#times):

```js
const dayNames = (n = 7) => _.times(n, i => moment().day(i).format('dddd'));

const result = dayNames();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```